# Only animate only one transform property

Tags: css

I have a css after selector that I'm trying to just animate the X position but not sure how to stop all the other transform functions from happening also. Whats the transition-property I need for translateX ?

```
.myLink {
    &:hover .myText:after {
      transition: transform 0.6s;
      transform: translateX(3px);
    }
  .myText {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      border-top: 2px solid $blue;
      border-right: 2px solid $blue;
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you upload a viewable copy somewhere, like jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: you cannot, transfrom is **one** property, use top/bottom instead of translate

Comment: Thanks  @Temani Afif